# Django filtered Viewset, need to annotate sum over all filtered rows. Group by "all"?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There are hundreds of questions here on various django annotate/aggregate constructions and filters but I couldn't find this simple use-case asked (or answered).

I have a "Payments" model and associated ListAPIView ViewSet endpoint with nicely setup DjangoFilters so the client can filter on created__lte, created__gte, company= etc.

Now I want to add an endpoint that derives from the above but only returns the sum of some fields and count of the total filtered objects.

I know exactly how to do this if I would just write the View "from scratch" (I can just hack the DRF View into executing get_queryset().aggregate() then feeding into a serializer and returning), but I want to do it in a "Django-way" if possible.

For example, combined with a serializer that defines "total_amount" and "nbr", this (almost) works:

```
queryset = models.Payment.objects.values('company').annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'),
                                                             nbr=Count('id'))
```

The values() call groups by "company" (a sub-field of Payment), which in combination with annotate() performs a sum by all company payments and annotates with total_amount/nbr. Adding filtering query parameters magically adjusts what goes into the annotation properly.

The problem is, what if I don't want to group (or even filter) by "company", I just want to "group by all"? Is there a way to do that?

I realize this is already a bit magical but the Django-esque way of doing grouping for annotation is this as far as I know.

I also realize I'm probably really better off just by hijacking .retrieve() to evaluate the queryset with .aggregate() tacked at the end and on-the-fly creating the response... still curious though :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the "hack", overriding list() in the View with an .aggregate call and the packing it for the Response through a serializer. This was the most canonical way I could figure out (I mean, re-using as many of the moving parts of Django/DRF as possible like automatic filtering of the queryset, serializing etc).

Bonus: note the Coalesce() wrap which is needed because Sum() doesn't return 0 if the set is empty.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    stats = queryset.aggregate(total_amount=Coalesce(Sum('amount'), 0),
                               total_vat=Coalesce(Sum('vat'), 0),
                               nbr_payments=Count('id'))
    # .aggregate() returns a dict of the results, not a QuerySet. Wrap it 
    # into a response through the serializer.
    sclass = self.get_serializer_class()
    return Response(sclass(stats).data)
```